# ARM Assembly - Why does my app crash when zeroing r7?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, arm

I'm currently having a weird issue when trying to run a C program that calls a very simple ARM assembly function. Here's my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void getNumber(int* pointer);

int main()
{
    int* pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));

    getNumber(pointer);

    printf("%d\n", *pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's my assembly code:

```
.section .text
.align 4
.arm
.global getNumber
.type getNumber STT_FUNC

getNumber:
    mov  r1, #0
    str  r1, [r0]
    bx   lr
```

So far so good. However, if I add a line with `mov r7, #0` at the top of `getNumber`, the program segfaults when trying to access `pointer`. After inspecting it with gdb I noticed now the pointer itself is stored at a very low address, such as 0xa.

Now, I did a bit of research and apparently r7 is the frame pointer for THUMB code (according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253599%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). However, I'm clearly stating I don't want to use THUMB instructions in the `.arm` line in my assembly code. Why on earth is it failing?

I'm compiling both the .c and .s files using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc, and I'm running the program on a Cortex-A8 based board running Arch Linux.

Edit: The program runs fine if I compile using the -fomit-frame-pointer flag. However, I still want to know why is it using r7 as the frame pointer.

Edit 2: It's still failing even if I use `.code 32` instead of `.arm`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [ARM Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) specifies the following:

> A subroutine must preserve the contents of the registers r4-r8, r10, r11 and SP (and r9 in PCS variants that designate r9 as v6).

So your assembly language subroutine must save & restore r7 if it uses it.

You might be avoiding the problem with your small test program by by not compiling for Thumb mode, but you're just accidentally avoiding the problem.  Anything that links to your assembly routine is entitled to expect that r7 will be preserved.

Comment: This. A thousand times this. Mixing assembly with higher-level languages without a thorough understanding of the ABI in use is _asking for trouble_.

Comment: Indeed you're right. I should've thought of that way before I started coding.

I'm curious, though: if I had saved/restored r7 like I should have, would the program still crash unless I compiled it using -marm?

Comment: @Phil: I believe it should work fine even with thumb code mixed with arm code.  The ARM ABI specifies that the ARM's interwork between thumb and ARM mode should be used. However, I think that it's possible to force the compiler (by options or configuration) to *not* default to using interwork, so I think there might be very odd situations/configurations where thumb code calling your function will not work because the compiler might not generate the necessary interwork call.

Comment: I didn't have the ARM board to try it myself yesterday, but today I tested it and apparently saving the registers fixes it even if I compile without -marm.

I find it weird, tough, that the Procedure Call Standard doesn't say anything about saving the link register. BL saves it automatically when branching to another assembly subroutine, but (at least when compiling with gcc) the link register isn't saved when jumping from C to assembly.

Comment: @Phil, the link register doesn't need to be saved/restored. The only time it needs to be saved is when a caller needs to save its own return address before calling a subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You're crashing the program because your are corrupting the frame pointer, like you mentioned.  There is really no rhyme or reason to the convention.  Just that ARM reserves certain registers for certain things.  Kinda like in x86 esp is the stack pointer.

Here's a pretty good reference for registers to avoid:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253599(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253599%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)